# ASP.NET Datasheet Component

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I need data editing capabilities like the one in Microsoft SharePoint Datasheet View (user can add/edit records excel-like, support copy&paste operations). I understand that SharePoint uses ActiveX to do this, however :

- Is there any commercial/free component that I can use?
- Is there any way I can re-use SharePoint ActiveX on my project?